# How to update a gem in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a ruby script with the requisite gems specified within it e.g

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bundler/inline'
require 'matrix'
gemfile do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  ruby '2.7.3'
  gem 'colorize'
  gem 'pry'
end

puts "warning".colorize(:red)
```

Normally to update a gem, I would type something like `bundle update colorize`, but this returns an error

```
Could not locate Gemfile
```

So how do I update a gem in this script. Is there an equivalent of a Gemfile.lock that I can list?

Comment: Why would you need to update? Just specify a high enough version in the inline gemfile.

Comment: I could, but then end up with lots of constraints in the gemfile, so unless I suspect it might break things, prefer to just do ```bundle update gem_name```,  which I can do with a gemfile.

Comment: Well you can’t using inline. As you say, there is no lock file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because using bundler in a single-file ruby script uses the latest constrained gem installed, in order to update one of the gems, you just have to run this (according to your example)

```
gem update colorize
```

Now your script will use the latest `colorize` gem version.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](https://bundler.io/v2.3/guides/bundler_in_a_single_file_ruby_script.html) running the file will install the dependencies. Without a lock file being generated, though, you might want to manually specify versions in your `gemfile` block:

```rb
gemfile do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  ruby '2.7.3'
  gem 'colorize', '~> 0.8.1'
  gem 'pry', '~> 0.14.1'
end
```

Your script likely won't be compatible with all versions of a library, so it's probably a good idea to add version constraints when there's no lock file. Then when you want to upgrade, you update the number and Bundler should install the new version.